# SQL using SUM of SUM

Tags: sql, join, sum

I can calculate the sums with the sql as separately as in this image.

```
SELECT ((SELECT ((SUM(TRANSFERRED * AVGVALUE) + SUM(PURCASH)) / SUM(ONHAND)) 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE STOCKREF = ITEMREF AND INVENNO = - 1)* RL.VALUE) AS MALIYET 
FROM N_RECIPE RC INNER JOIN N_RECIPELINE RL ON RC.ID = RL.RECIPEREF 
WHERE RC.ID = 10
```

[image: sql output]

I want to calculate the sum of these records, but i can't.

I tried it this way but it didn't work.

```
SELECT (SUM(SELECT ((SUM(TRANSFERRED * AVGVALUE) + SUM(PURCASH)) / SUM(ONHAND)) 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE STOCKREF = ITEMREF AND INVENNO = - 1)* RL.VALUE) AS MALIYET 
FROM N_RECIPE RC INNER JOIN N_RECIPELINE RL ON RC.ID = RL.RECIPEREF 
WHERE RC.ID = 10
```

Thanks...

Comment: try with `rollup` if you want to total all these value at bottom

Comment: What DBMS are you using? And please post your table schema, sample data and expected outcome.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Your code is pretty inscrutable.  You have a correlated subquery but it is a mystery what columns come from which tables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use subselect:

```
SELECT Sum(S.MALIYET)
FROM (
SELECT ((SELECT ((SUM(TRANSFERRED * AVGVALUE) + SUM(PURCASH)) / SUM(ONHAND)) 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE STOCKREF = ITEMREF AND INVENNO = - 1)* RL.VALUE) AS MALIYET 
FROM N_RECIPE RC INNER JOIN N_RECIPELINE RL ON RC.ID = RL.RECIPEREF 
WHERE RC.ID = 10) As S
```